# C++ stack corrupted with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote a simple pointers code in c++, and I'm getting the stack corrupted runtime error around "str".
I know it gives this error if you're trying to get to an unassigned place in an array, but in this case when the pointer gets to '\0' the while stops.
could it be the ptr continuing to adavnce in memory and pointing at '\0'?
Thanks in advance! : - )

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #define SIZE 5
    void CHANGE(char str[]);

    void CHANGE(char str[])
    {
        char *ptr=str;
         while(*ptr!='\0')
         {
            if( ( (*ptr>='a')&&(*ptr<='z') )|| ( (*ptr>='A')&&(*ptr<='Z') ) )
             {
                 if(*ptr=='z')
                     *ptr='a';
                 else if(*ptr=='Z')
                     *ptr='A';
                 else
                    (*ptr)++;

             }

             ptr++;
         }

    }

    void main()
    {

        char str[SIZE];
        cout<<"please enter a sring\n";
        cin>>str;
        CHANGE(str);
        cout<<str<<"\n";
    }
```

Comment: Could it be you're using a string longer than four characters (since the zero-term eats one of your declared 5) ? What input are you testing with?

Comment: Do you have some requirement of using character arrays instead of `std::string`? Anyway, your `main` signature is non-standard and you assume that `'a'` through `'z'` and `'A'` through `'Z'` have contiguous character codes, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: NO NO NO NOOOOOOOOOO DO NOT USE DEFINE MACROS WHEN YOU MEAN CONSTANTS USE STD::STRING IF YOU MEAN STRING. AND A BOOK, GET A BOOOOOK

Comment: I'm *so* going to work tomorrow and doing just that, knowing somewhere out there, phresh is killing a kitten.

Comment: @phresnel I agree, but please calm down. This isn't 4chan. xD

Comment: @WhozCraig rather place `#define TRUE FALSE` somwhere.

Comment: Also, `main` must return `int`!

Comment: @Najzero **perfect** I'll do that too

Comment: @Zoidberg: I agree, I was beeing uncalm there. But the quality of questions recently, their redundance, the lack of basic knowledge, lets me feel this is soon becoming programming-chan.

Comment: @WhozCraig, I actually did something like `#define true rand()%2` and `#define false rand()%2` once to, I believe, my summative when it was pretty much done, just to see the funny results.

Comment: @chris with the manditory `// happy debugging suckers` comment I assume?

Comment: @chris your too young to remember the old pre F77 days; ah memories. slipping a good-old "1=2" on someones deck. =P

Comment: @chris: With `// Don't change this, I know it works!`

Comment: @Najzero, Debugging that? Ain't nobody got time for that!

Comment: `cout<<"please enter a sring\n";` You've made a typo there. It should be `std::cout << "please enter a char[SIZE]\n"`.

Comment: @chris srsly. *awesome* idea. I'd use a bigger number, depending on the loop frequency of course, but I *have* to do that. (were in the middle of a beta release, so the panic should be both wide-spread and near-instantaneous).

Comment: @WhozCraig, I can just imagine how that would turn out. Hey! Who turned on the undefined behaviour?

Comment: @chris I *did* do something similar once for an in-house beta, rand()-faulting on a specific domain-login (the QA managers). It would crash about 1-8 launches. He was about-ready to climb the walls while none of his testers could reproduce the problem. it was *awesome*.

Comment: @WhozCraig, That is pure evil.

Comment: ah yeah, the student I'm teaching typed 5 chars insted of 4, sorry for the stupid question : ]]

Comment: @user1889572, Teach them `std::string`!

Comment: @user1889572 Ah, nice. Now this is a good opportunity to teach that student how silly it is to use fixed size buffers for code like this and how using `std::string` and `std::getline` are much more superior. Or, I hope not... for you to learn that.

Comment: I am desillusionized. You are a teacher, and have not done your homework yourself? On the other hand, I had bad teachers in C++, too. Luckily, I knew enough already to not learn bad things from them.

Comment: @phresnel, Perhaps just a student teaching another student. That's quite common. Your point still holds, though, but it does take time to get acquainted with all of the idiomatic things to do and use.

Comment: @chris: True, though I am more familiar with the terms "classmate" and "fellow student". And yeah, especially in C++ it takes time. But the book advice is so common here .... hmm.

Comment: @phresnel, Luring anyone into SO will do wonders. My code and understanding of C++ was completely and utterly terrible before coming here. To this day, I've still only had the opportunity of a first-year C++ high-school course.

Comment: @user1889572: Please teach your student C++. Not C with a C++ compiler. http://liveworkspace.org/code/2BFDVj$1

Comment: I'm familiar with getline and vica versa. I had this course two years ago and I', teaching a student in 2nd year, that's how they teach them here...

Comment: Which educational establishment is this?

Comment: @chris: Yeah you are right, I should meditate more. (@)user1889572: Sorry for the tone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you defined SIZE 5, you can get inputs up to size 4 because you are considering it as a null-terminated string. so in case you enter more characters than SIZE your CHANGE function will try to access memory where it hasn't been allocated.
Hope it helped.

Answer (score -2):

```
int main()
```

It works for me.
By the way, SIZE should be much higher.

```
#define SIZE 10000
```

Comment: ***Why*** `10000` and not `10001`?

Comment: Because 9999 isn't quite enough, and 10001 is just too damn big ??

Comment: /me checks calendar. Nope, still not 2013-04-01.

Comment: Hehe :D Maybe

    #define SIZE 0x3f3f3f3f // just kiddin'